# convert list elements to dictionary python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list in the format below

```
['iad-cgnt:248.600000,ord-cgnt:319.301775,iad-mci:331.185117,nyc-inap:316.122925,hkg-pccw:452.789753,ord-tata:243.000000,sjc-l3:321.487964,pvg-cu2:40.912496,nyc-bgp:382.419130,nyc-cgnt:332.477115,bgl-rel:311.344224,pvg-cu1:38.750000']
```

I need to construct a dictionary from this list in this format:

```
{'iad-cgnt' : 248.600000 , 'ord-cgnt':319.301775 } ... and  so on.
```

Could you please suggest how to do that ?

Comment: I have tried to split based on for d in final:
    parts = d.split(':')
    fin.append(parts)
print fin but it does not split the way I want on ':'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dictionary comprehension:

```
L = ['iad-cgnt:248.600000,ord-cgnt:319.301775,iad-mci:331.185117,...pvg-cu1:38.750000']
{k: float(v) for k, v in (item.split(':') for item in L[0].split(','))}
```

Result with values as floats:

```
{'bgl-rel': 311.344224,
 'hkg-pccw': 452.789753,
 'iad-cgnt': 248.6,
 'iad-mci': 331.185117,
 'nyc-bgp': 382.41913,
 'nyc-cgnt': 332.477115,
 'nyc-inap': 316.122925,
 'ord-cgnt': 319.301775,
 'ord-tata': 243.0,
 'pvg-cu1': 38.75,
 'pvg-cu2': 40.912496,
 'sjc-l3': 321.487964}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming:

```
data = 'iad-cgnt:248.600000,ord-cgnt:319.301775,iad-mci:331.185117,nyc-inap:316.122925,hkg-pccw:452.789753,ord-tata:243.000000,sjc-l3:321.487964,pvg-cu2:40.912496,nyc-bgp:382.419130,nyc-cgnt:332.477115,bgl-rel:311.344224,pvg-cu1:38.750000'
```

you can get dictionary by using:

```
dict([item.split(':') for item in data[0].split(',')])
```

as output

```
{'bgl-rel': '311.344224',
 'hkg-pccw': '452.789753',
 'iad-cgnt': '248.600000',
 'iad-mci': '331.185117',
 'nyc-bgp': '382.419130',
 'nyc-cgnt': '332.477115',
 'nyc-inap': '316.122925',
 'ord-cgnt': '319.301775',
 'ord-tata': '243.000000',
 'pvg-cu1': '38.750000',
 'pvg-cu2': '40.912496',
 'sjc-l3': '321.487964'}
```

Answer (score 0):

The item in the list is very close to the string representation of a dictionary to start with,
a little text fiddling gets it there:

```
zot = ['iad-cgnt:248.600000,ord-cgnt:319.301775,iad-mci:331.185117,nyc-inap:316.122925,hkg-pccw:452.789753,ord-tata:243.000000,sjc-l3:321.487964,pvg-cu2:40.912496,nyc-bgp:382.419130,nyc-cgnt:332.477115,bgl-rel:311.344224,pvg-cu1:38.750000']
s = '{"'+zot[0].replace(',', ',"').replace(':', '":')+'}'
d = eval(s)
print d.keys()
```

Gives the dictionary's keys:

```
['iad-cgnt', 'nyc-bgp', 'ord-cgnt', 'bgl-rel', 'nyc-cgnt', 'nyc-inap', 'sjc-l3', 'hkg-pccw', 'pvg-cu1', 'pvg-cu2', 'ord-tata', 'iad-mci']
```